# Is this a real picture of Jordan Peterson in New Zealand with a fan wearing a shirt that says "I'm a Proud Islamaphobe"?

Tags: islam, racism

Tweet reads

> This is @jordanbpeterson and a fan during his speaking tour in New Zealand. February 19th, 2019. Less than one month ago.

[image]

Did Jordan Peterson really take a picture with a fan wearing a shirt that says *"I'm a Proud Islamaphobe"*?

Comment: Was there something in particular that made you doubt its authenticity?

Comment: Search here https://www.omgvip.com/jordan-b-peterson-vip-photos/

Comment: @quant since when do we have to substantiate our skepticism? I found it online, and I didn't believe the claim (picture).

Comment: I don't understand why anyone cares whether it's real or fake. It's like I were to say that Tom Hanks lived next door to someone who liked to eat dogs. Why would anyone care, and why would people care enough to be skeptical?

Comment: @EvanCarroll you should read my question more literally. I was just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, that is a real account of the picture.

From [Avery](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/22367/avery) in the comments, it is legit. You can see it here on ["omgvip" in the album *"Jordan B Peterson VIP Photos - Auckland, NZ February 18, 2019"*](https://www.omgvip.com/jordan-peterson-february-18-2019/) In this album you can find Jordan Picture in the same attire taking pictures with 100 or so fans.

That [specific picture can be found here](https://farm8.static.flickr.com/7857/47089330412_9fda077edf_o.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91106/discussion-on-answer-by-evan-carroll-is-this-a-real-picture-of-jordan-peterson-i).